# How do you set a UI Element's Delegate from within Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, uistoryboard

I currently have two `UITextField`s, and I've created a new class that will be their `UITextFieldDelegate` (this class is not a view controller). Is there any way to connect the `.delegate` property of these text fields to this class from within Storyboard, or is this only possible programmatically?

Right-click dragging the `delegate` property under the Connections Inspector to the class didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Storyboard connections are only possible when connecting to the files set in the identity inspector. This probably has to do with the fact that the storyboard would need a reference to an instantiated version of your separate class but that won't necessarily be available because it is not in the storyboard. You might be able to get the behavior you're looking for by subclassing UITextField instead of setting a delegate.